# Replacing fragments inside ViewPager on RecyclerView click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have an activity called navigation and two fragments called OneFragment, Description Fragment.

The navigation activity contains these two fragments as code show below:

**navigation.java**

```
public class navigation extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_newsfeed,
        R.drawable.ic_livestream,
        R.drawable.ic_matches,
        R.drawable.ic_sort
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
   ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(),getString(R.string.newsfeed));
    adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), getString(R.string.livestream));
    adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(),getString(R.string.matches));
    adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(),getString(R.string.schedule));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}



@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.share) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.check) {

    } else if (id == R.id.rateus) {

    } else if (id == R.id.aboutus) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

This is **my Adapter** class:

```
public class PostAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter2.ViewHolder>{

public Context mContext;
public ArrayList<News_data> original_items = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<News_data> filtered_items = new ArrayList<>();
//   ItemFilter mFilters = new ItemFilter();

public PostAdapter2(Context mContext, ArrayList<News_data> postList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.original_items = postList;
    this.filtered_items = postList;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_news, parent, false);


    return new ViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    try {

        final News_data post = filtered_items.get(position);

        holder.txt_news_title.setText(post.getName_news());
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick() {

              //what to do to replace the OneFragment with the DescriptionFragment 

            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filtered_items.size();
}





public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    Context c;
    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    TextView txt_news_title,txt_desc;
    ImageView image_news;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txt_news_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_news_title);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);









    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.itemClickListener.onItemClick();

    }
    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener)
    {
        this.itemClickListener=itemClickListener;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to replace the **OneFragment** with The **DescriptionFragment** on Recyclerview item click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you cannot replace `Fragment`s inside `ViewPager`, but you can use `NestedFragment` to add a `ChildFragment` to your main `Fragment` like you do with `Activity`.
Just define a `FrameLayout` inside you **OneFragment** `Layout` and call `getChildFragmentManager` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager`. For example:

```
Fragment descriptionFragment = new DescriptionFragment ();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.nested_fragment_container, descriptionFragment ).commit();
```

For more info you can visit here:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

P.S: If you have more fragment than these **two** or you want your fragments to be **stand alone** you can use this library to get **instagram** like tabs:

https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav

Comment: Thanks you for the link, i have seen many news app that when u hit the recyclerview items a fragment with match parent attribute opens containing all detailed news..
I wanted to replace the OneFragmet totaly with the DescriptionFragment

Comment: unfortunately currently there is no way to replace fragments inside viewpager.. so we have to update fragments.
  I updated answer with a example, it's like how you use fragments inside an activity.. just a little different ^^

Comment: Hehe okay Thanks for your help

Comment: But if you really want to replace fragments totally I really suggest using mentioned library. I used it myself and it is indeed efficient a bug free ^^

Comment: If i used the one mentioned above can i move the tabs to the top ?

Comment: Yes, it has all the features you see in multi tabs app like Instagram. Pushing and Poping fragments to different tabs. Beside the Mentioned library is not coupled with a custom UI so you can use any View you want!

Comment: Wow ok i will use it soon.
I used this one : Fragment descriptionFragment = new DescriptionFragment ();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.nested_fragment_container, descriptionFragment ).commit();

I am getting cannot resolve getChildFragmentManager()

What i did : i passed to the adapter class getChildFragment
But what to add in the Adapter Constructor?

Comment: Just pass fragment or fragment Context to adapter.. also don't forget to define a FrameLayout as Fragment Container inside your OneFragment..
Cheers

Comment: Sorry for extended discussions,,i have successfully replaced my new fragment and i have added the detailed news on the fragment but now how i get back to the OneFragment? i have added a small back button top left the layout fragment..So how do i handle that?

Comment: You should Override Activity's onBackPressed and pass the back press to current Fragment shown inside viewpager, then you can pass the back press to child fragment.. Since handling backpress is a complex process feel free to ask a new question.. ^^
I will be around so don't worry..

Comment: I have only little problem when i pause the app and resume it the app relauches from SplashScreen..so how could i handle the onPause() and onResume() so that the app don t restart

Comment: I think the problem lies in your onCreate and onCreateView methods I can't help you unless I see your code ><